# How to resume the exoplayer after call

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am not able to resume the video in exoplayer after I received a call. Which is starting from beginning.

Here is my code in onPause()

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    TelephonyManager telePhoneManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telePhoneManager != null) {
        telePhoneManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
    if(!backPressed){
        releasePlayer();
    }else{
        player.setBackgrounded(true);
    }
shutterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And onResume() as follows,

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (player == null) {
            preparePlayer();
    } else {
        player.setBackgrounded(false);
    }
}
```

can any one help me out from this issue?

Comment: However its too late, but for other googlers, try using player.setPlayWhenReady(false) to pause and player.setPlayWhenReady(true) to resume playing.

Comment: on resume lag video for a second only audio playes

Answer (score 2):

Set AudioAttributes to your player.

```
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE)
            .build();
.
.
.
simpleExoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes);
```

onPause()

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releasePlayer();
}
```

onResume()

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (simpleExoPlayer == null) {
        initializePlayer();
    }
    startPlay();
}
```

releasePlayer()

```
 private void releasePlayer() {
    if (simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        playbackPosition = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        currentWindow = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex();
        playWhenReady = simpleExoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
        simpleExoPlayer.removeListener(componentListener);
        simpleExoPlayer.release();
        simpleExoPlayer = null;
    }
}
```